# Algorithm encryption possible?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, cryptography, discrete-mathematics

Algorithms are relationships, let algorithm f, receive data d, it will have output o. 
Like so:

```
f(d) = o
```

We have encryption algorithms, such that, with data `d` and a publicKey as input we receive `d'` as output. Also, with d' and a privateKey we can recover the original `d`. 
Like so:

```
encrypt(d, publicKey) = d'
decrypt(d', privateKey) = d
```

Algorithms themselves are a kind of data. So here's the question:

Is it possible to create an algorithm J that takes as input algorithm `f` and produces a `f'` such that:

```
J(f) = f'
f'(d') = o'
```

That is to say, does the current mathematics theory rule out the creation of algorithms that work on encrypted data an produce encrypted output that the algorithm itself cannot decrypt?

Comment: I think you need a more concrete example of what's going on here.

Comment: you might wanna ask this in security.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

Comment: And this question belongs to [Crypto SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Homomorphic%20)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics and/or cryptography.

Comment: Have an upvote, no idea why this was downvoted. Seems to me this is a perfectly reasonable question. Also, regarding "the algorithm cannot decrypt", this is somewhat blurry and needs clarification via a security model. Due to the computability problem being involved, this would be better suited on CS or Cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the term function instead of algorithm, since an algorithm may be something like "check temperature, if greater then 72F turn on air conditioner compressor". And it will be kind of irreversible since the compressor turned on does not say anything about previous temperature value.

On functions, there are Surjective functions that as you know are irreversible like for example f(x) = x^2

So the answer is No, it is possible and common to have functions that once encrypted cannot be decrypted, it is the principle behind all hash functions.

Comment: That example of an "irreversible function" is not suitable in the crypto-sense of irreversibility. Given some y>=0, we can say x was either -sqrt(y) or sqrt(y) which is far more than a secure cipher should allow you to derive. Also. the last paragraph is wrong in the common interpretation of "breaking an encryption algorithm" (while it is of course true that "you can't find the preimage of every image with probability 1 for a given noninjective function")

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize the nature of your question: If I keep the method secret (i.e. encrypt the algorithm), then will things be better?  In common security nerd terms, that's called [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and it may help you, but it won't get you far.

Yes, there are functions which take functions as inputs (i.e. your algorithms).  Not exactly an easy task to complete when implemented via code.